# "Qt: Untested Windows 10.0 version detected!" when using python-vlc

Tags: python, qt, vlc

I'm setting up a program to play youtube links in vlc, and I get this error. I don't have Qt installed, and to be honest I'm not even fully sure what it is or what it has to do with anything.

I've tried to ignore the error using `try` but this didn't work

```
import pafy
import vlc

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

Comment: What this message is telling you is that Python-vlc and/or one of its dependencies is using the Qt libraries. More specifically, the version of the used Qt libraries is not a version that has full support for Windows 10. For example, Qt 5.6 is the first version with full Windows 10 support. So the version of the Qt libraries used must be built with a version lower than 5.6

Comment: @ManuelH is there a way to fix this then? or should i look for a way to do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! My actual VLC install was out of date. Reinstalled that (twice, had to make sure both python and VLC were 32 bit) and everything worked!